# NodeJS Selenium Chrome Headless Driver hang on getting website from url

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm using Selenium with NodeJS to get some specific element from website. But my script is working on Debian system with only terminal. So i used Headless Chrome Driver, but unfortunately scripts hangs on getting website. I was trying put some public addresses like for example google.com but it doesn't work.

This is my script:

```
const chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
const firefox = require("selenium-webdriver/firefox");
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require("selenium-webdriver");

let driver = new Builder()
  .forBrowser("chrome")
  .setChromeOptions(
    new chrome.Options().headless().windowSize({
      width: 640,
      height: 480,
    })
  )
  .build();

const visit = async () => {
  try {
    console.log("This console log is executing");
    await driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    console.log("This console log is not executing");    
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

visit();
```

There is no error output when executing my script.
I've tested connection with google.com by using curl and everything is working properly.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: I ended up getting it to work for me. I'm on linux and after I ran "sudo yum -y groupinstall "GNOME Desktop"", it worked.